# Payment system migration

Tags: c#

[GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/paydemo)

There need to be a software design supporting gradual migration from one payment system (E-xact) to another (Stripe). Credit cards data are stored outside, so I would like to use both systems in parallel for a while to do not make all users to re-enter credit card data.

Here is what I have at the moment in the domain core:

```
public interface IMainPaymentAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
}

public interface IPaymentAdapter : IPaymentService
{
}

public interface IPaymentGateway : IPaymentService
{
}

public interface IPaymentService
{
    Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card);
    Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount);
}
```

The idea is that `IPaymentService` defines API shape, `IPaymentAdaptor` is about to be implemented for each payment system in use, `IPaymentGateway` dispatches calls to the right adaptor based on a `BillingId` and is supposed to be injected into the consuming code:

```
public abstract class BillingId
{
    public static BillingId Parse(string text)
    {
        var parts = text.Split('/');
        return (BillingId)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(BillingId<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(parts[0])),
            parts[1]);
    }

    protected BillingId(string value) => Value = value;
    public string Value { get; }
    public abstract Type Adapter { get; }
    public override string ToString() => 
        $"{Adapter.AssemblyQualifiedName}/{Value}";
}

public class BillingId<TAdapter> : BillingId 
    where TAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
    public BillingId(string value) : base(value) { }
    public override Type Adapter => typeof(TAdapter);
}
```

My gateway looks like this – note that card registration call is always dispatched to the current `IMainPaymentAdaptor` implementation, while everything else goes to the adaptor that provided the billing id originally:

```
[Service]
public class PaymentGateway : IPaymentGateway
{
    public PaymentGateway(IServiceProvider provider) => Provider = provider;
    IServiceProvider Provider { get; }

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        await Adapter().RegisterAsync(card);

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Adapter(id).ChargeAsync(id, amount); 

    IPaymentAdapter Adapter() => Adapter(typeof(IMainPaymentAdapter));
    IPaymentAdapter Adapter(BillingId id) => Adapter(id.Adapter);
    IPaymentAdapter Adapter(Type type) => 
        (IPaymentAdapter)Provider.GetService(type);
}
```

Here is what I have in a Stripe adapter assembly:

```
public interface IStripeAdapter : IMainPaymentAdapter
{
}

[Service]
public class StripeAdapter : IStripeAdapter
{
    StripeClient Client { get; } = new StripeClient();

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        new BillingId<IStripeAdapter>(await Client.RegisterAsync(card));

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Client.ChargeAsync(id.Value, amount);
}
```

Note that `E-xact` adapter (a decommissioning one) should be based on `IPaymentAdaptor`, not the `IMainPaymentAdapter`:

```
public interface IEXactAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
}
```

What would you say about this design approach? Does it look clean enough?

Comment: You should probably ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here. I suggest flagging your question for migration.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica This question contains demo code - a very oversimplified version of the real solution to discuss design aspects, which makes it more reasonable to ask here I think. And, it is necessary to say, CR is almost dead...

Comment: @Dmitry I checked Code Review.  It's had 10 new questions posted to it in the last couple of hours, and several questions answered on the front page.  It's hardly dead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, I know (I am top 0.82% there :), it is just difficult to see  a discussion on code architecture there anymore - it does not generate much interest and you would not count many questions like that. CR is supposed to be about low level code details, not about quoted solution high level overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design could be significantly simplified by eliminating generics, reflection and the multiple variations of the payment interface. Here's how I would do it instead (I've skipped async/await to keep the example simple):

```
class BillingId {
    ProviderId providerId; // "Exact" or "Stripe" (can be a string or enum)
    RegistrationId registrationId; // an ID specific to the provider
}

interface IPaymentProvider {
    RegistrationId Register(CreditCard card);
    void Charge(RegistrationId id, decimal amount);
}

class PaymentGateway {
    Dictionary<ProviderId, IPaymentProvider> providers;
    ProviderId primaryProvider; // "Stripe"

    BillingId Register(CreditCard card) {
        var registrationId = providers[primaryProvider].Register(card);
        return new BillingId(primaryProvider, registrationId);
    }

    void Charge(BillingId billingId, decimal amount) {
        providers[billingId.ProviderId].Charge(billingId.RegistrationId, amount);
    }
}
```

In general, you don't want to rely too much on the language's type system to model domain concepts such as the payment provider type. Further reading: [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Also it's a good idea to separate the provider interface (`IPaymentProvider` in the above example) from the client interface (`PaymentGateway`) since they work at different levels. Providers only need to deal with `RegistrationId`s while the client API is a facade to multiple providers. Further reading: [Separate API and SPI](http://wiki.netbeans.org/API_Design#Separate_API_for_clients_from_support_API)

Comment: enum would make my domain assembly to know about all payment system adapter assemblies, that does not look right for me. Having a name property on SPI helps to get rid of reflection though, thanks. Would you go with API/SPI separation when API is wide and volatile, and you would like a compiler to check for consistency between them? I just see it as `interface ISpi : IApi { string Name { get; } }`  now because of it. Could shared stuff just go to extension methods for the interface as well as `SpiBase` class?

Comment: @DmitryNogin: Putting the name on the SPI is fine. I wouldn't do `interface ISpi : IApi` because that's a dependency in the wrong direction (API depends on SPI, not the other way). The idea of separation is that you want to shield the API (what clients call) from changes to the SPI (what providers implement) and vice versa.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I would personally implement a functionality enricher in a separate decorator without mixing it with dispatching. SRP rules :)

Answer (score 1):

I think having identical interfaces under different names misses the point of interfaces. The point of interfaces is that you can have provider1, provider2, unittestprovider, upload-to-my-botnet-provider etc. all exposing the *same* interface.

Expressing a provider model

Once you have multiple providers, they are commonly mapped using a dependency injection framework. In other words, you say this once

```
RegisterType(IPaymentService, PaymentService1)
```

and whenever a payment service is needed, someone would say

```
var provider = GetInstance(IPaymentService)
```

and the framework will procure said provider. This reduces the impact of making such changes.

Designing for change notification

My understanding of your goal is that you want to capture credit card information as transactions are processed, so they can be stored with your new system.

To accomplish this, create a wrapper that wraps the actual payment provider. The wrapper would also expose IPaymentService, use the inner provider to do the actual work, and also perform its own task.

A credit card change is best expressed in a publisher/subscriber model. In this model, the publisher creates a message indicating it has gained knowledge of the data. It publishes this message with no knowledge of any recipients. A recipient can subscribe to such messages and process them as they see fit. The two advantages are that the recipients are not hardcoded thus easier to change, plus the implementation usually is asynchronous so it will not hold up your payment processing.

Comment: 1) It is a way, way cheaper to register services as implemented interfaces by marking them with a [Service] attribute, here is how it works for [Autofac](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/x-utils/blob/master/X.IoC.Autofac/AssemblyRegistration.cs). Proper interface design allows to do not mess with custom registration in 95% of cases. 2) I am not interested in any kind of notifications, I need to persist a BillingId with my customer profile, in a way allowing to subsequently charge through the billing system I registered a credit card with as keeping it locally is a security risk.